# Is there a handlebar way to break lines after each {{#each}} in markdown?

Tags: json, markdown, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I have a JSON dataset which I pass through handlebars to generate .md files, something like this:

```
{{#each items}}| **{{name}}** | {{system.d.v}} | {{system.a.v}} | {{system.p}} |{{/each}}
```

... and I want to break lines after every single {{/each}}. One of many things I tried was this:

```
{{#each things}}| **{{name}}** | {{system.d.v}} | {{system.a.v}} | {{system.p}} |</br>{{/each}}
```

**The thing is:** the output is markdown (tried `\n` and ASCII as well) but I am not able to break lines, the output is a single very long line like `| data | data  | data  |<br/>| data | data  | data  |<br/>| data | data  | data  |<br/>| data | data  | data  |<br/>| data | data  | data  |<br/>| data | data  | data  |<br/>| data | data  | data  |<br/>| data | data  | data  |<br/>| data | data  | data  |<br/>|`

**... and instead should look like this for example:**

```
| name | data  | data  | data  |
| name | data  | data  | data  |
| name | data  | data  | data  |
| name | data  | data  | data  |
| name | data  | data  | data  |
| name | data  | data  | data  |
```

I searched here with no success, tried different helpers and ways to type , from ASCII to HTML and now I feel like in a dead end. User-software to display result is obsidian.md but it does not matter as far as the plain text gets printed in a single line. CSS or HTML does not solve the thing because it have to be a plain, seperated lines for markdown.

Please help me :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[solved] it by altering my earlier tries in the handlebar helper, it works now with:

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper('breakline', function(text) {
    text = "\n";
    return text;
});
```

and calling it by the following in the markdown template:

```
{{#each things}}| **{{name}}** | {{system.d.v}} | {{system.a.v}} | {{system.p}} |**{{{breaklines test}}}**{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add \n character for a line break instead of **br** tag, ore set **br** tag in quote marks.

> {{system.p\n}}

> "
> "

Comment: That results in an error:
```
Handlers Error: Parse error on line 73:
....v}} | {{system.p\n}} |{{/each}}

-----------------------^
Expecting 'ID', got 'INVALID'
```
furthermore there is still an `|` to end the line which needs to be "printed"


EDIT for your edit ;) --> I tried every single possible solution I could think of, including `\n` or `&#13;` etc. `br` in quote marks does not help either

Comment: Have you tried to add after last |

{{\n}}

Comment: yes and also variants too like html tags with no success, throughs out an error too: `Handlers Error: Parse error on line 73:
... | {{system.p}} |{{\n}}{{/each}}

## 
-----------------------^
Expecting 'ID', 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'BOOLEAN', 'UNDEFINED', 'NULL', 'DATA', got 'INVALID'` EDIT: arrow points to the \ of the added  \n